# Why hooks inside component keep getting triggered multiple times whenever the dependencies change even though they only change once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a screen in React Native that has a hook which is fetching data from an API endpoint to show it in a FlatList and another hook, that is taking the state "apiVersion" and checks if app version is higher or lower.

The issue is that every time I go onto GrandPrixScreen the screen keeps re-rendering and the useGetGrandPrix hook keeps calling the api, like 3-4 times (useCheckVersion keeps getting called as well, but I'm expecting that as I want to check the version on each api call).

**Screen**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';

import { useGetGrandPrix } from '../hooks/api';
import { useCheckVersion } from '../hooks/system';

function GrandPrixScreen(props) {
  const { data, apiVersion, loading, errorMessage } = useGetGrandPrix();
  const { isNewVersion } = useCheckVersion(apiVersion);

  if (loading) {
    return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
  }

  if (errorMessage) {
    return <Text>{errorMessage}</Text>;
  }

  if (isNewVersion) {
    return <Text>Please update app to latest version.</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <GrandPrix
          name={item.name}
          length={item.length}
          onPress={() =>
            navigation.navigate('GrandPrixDetailsScreen', { item })
          }
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}

export default GrandPrixScreen;
```

**useCheckVersion**

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

import { APP } from '../../../utils/constants/app';

export const useCheckVersion = (apiVersion) => {
  const [isNewVersion, setNewVersion] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getVersion = async () => {
      const checkVersion = () => {
        if (apiVersion === APP.VERSION) {
          return false;
        } else if (apiVersion > APP.VERSION) {
          return true;
        }
      };
      const version = checkVersion(apiVersion);

      let versionPrompt = {
        dateLastPrompt: null,
        dateNextPrompt: null,
      };

      const currentWeekday = new Date().getUTCDay();
      const currentPromptUTC = new Date().toISOString();
      const nextPromptUTC = new Date(currentPromptUTC);
      nextPromptUTC.setDate(nextPromptUTC.getDate() + 7);
      nextPromptUTC.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

      if (version === false) {
        const storageItem = await AsyncStorage.getItem('versionPrompt');
        if (storageItem) {
          await AsyncStorage.removeItem('versionPrompt');
        }
      } else if (version === true) {
        const storageItem = await AsyncStorage.getItem(
          'versionPrompt',
          (err, result) => JSON.parse(result)
        );
        if (!storageItem) {
          versionPrompt = {
            dateLastPrompt: currentPromptUTC,
            dateNextPrompt: nextPromptUTC,
          };
          await AsyncStorage.setItem(
            'versionPrompt',
            JSON.stringify(versionPrompt)
          );
          return setNewVersion(true);
        } else if (storageItem) {
          const dateNextPrompt = new Date(storageItem.dateNextPrompt);
          const currentDate = new Date();

          if (dateNextPrompt < currentDate && currentWeekday > 2) {
            versionPrompt = {
              dateLastPrompt: currentPromptUTC,
              dateNextPrompt: nextPromptUTC,
            };
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('versionPrompt', versionPrompt);
            return setNewVersion(true);
          }
        }
      }
    };
    getVersion();
  }, [apiVersion]);

  return { isNewVersion };
};
```

**useGetGranPrix**

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import { getToken } from '../../../services/common/auth/storage';
import { getGranPrix } from '../../../services/common/api/circuits';

export const useGetGranPrix = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [apiVersion, setApiVersion] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const token = await getToken();
      const response = await getGranPrix(token);

      if (!response.ok) {
        setErrorMessage('Could not retrieve data.');
        setLoading(false);
      } else if (response.ok) {
        setData(response.data.list);
        setApiVersion(response.data.version);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    getData();
  }, []);

  return { data, apiVersion, loading, errorMessage };
};
```

**getGranPrix**

```js
import { apiClient } from './client';
import { GET_GRAN_PRIX } from '@env';

export const getGranPrix = (token) => {
  apiClient.setHeader('token', token);
  return apiClient.get(GET_GRAN_PRIX);
};
```

If I remove the useCheckVersion hook, useGetGrandPrix stops calling the api so many times, but I need the useCheckVersion hook.

How could I fix this?

I only want one api call and the useCheckVersion to run only when there is a new apiVersion.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, the component does not rerender forever but only a few times. This is probably because useEffect is called multiple times when you use StrictMode. In the past it was the only hook that is called only once in StrictMode but I think they have changed that. I use the following Custom-Hook instead of useEffect and it works for me:

```js
export default function useCallOnce(callback: EffectCallback) {
  const called = useRef(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    if (called.current) return
    called.current = true
    return callback()
  }, [])
}
```